# Why knownStates and pulledStates are always 0 on my full node?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, synchronization

It's the second time that I run a Geth in full node. The first one got synced fully, but the second one did not sync after a week. Both servers have the same configuration and infrastructure. Using `eth.syncing` I receive a strange output on the second server as below:

```
> eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 5169781,
  highestBlock: 9967108,
  knownStates: 0,
  pulledStates: 0,
  startingBlock: 5175548
}
```

As you see, currentBlock is about half of highestBlock, and knownStates and pulledStates are both 0. May you tell me why these values are 0 and what is the matter here?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi I 'm having the same problem, and worse because my currentBlock is almost the same as highestBlock. It seems that it is always a few blocks away. How did you solve this?

Answer (score 3):

The node first will synchronize blocks then states. In your case it hasn't finished synchronizing blocks yet.

Comment: I'm also having the same issue and my currentBlock is almost the same as highestBlock, never seems to catch up. It seems that it is always a few blocks away. How did you solve this?

Comment: @EvgenyKolyakov You have to wait. There isn't much more you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Holy moly....

To fix it I had to restart it completely (deleting the data) and using:

```
docker run -d -v /data/binance:/root --name binance-smart-chain-node -p 0.0.0.0:8545:8545 -p 0.0.0.0:8546:8546 -p 0.0.0.0:6060:6060 -p 30311:30311 -p 30311:30311/udp vlddm/binance-smart-chain-node:latest --syncmode full --cache 4096 --rpc --rpccorsdomain="*" --rpcaddr="0.0.0.0"
```

The important part was `--syncmode full` , without that, the blockNumber (in the web3 client) was always returning as Zero (0).

Comment: With the `--syncmode mode` you control the synchronization method. In full mode it downloads one block then the block state, then the next block, and so on. Then `blockNumber` is the latest synchronized block, which will not be the most recent until it has finishes syncing. A disadvantage is that you are downloading very old states unnecessarily (it may be useful if you are building an archive node).

Comment: Thanks and I understand, but with mode "snap" for example (from https://github.com/vlddm/binance-smart-chain-node) I didn't receive any data in my web3 client because it seemed the node couldn't catch up with the latest block to start getting the statuses.

Comment: * Sorry, states.

BTW, what are these states?

Comment: In fast and snap `blockNumber` will return 0 until the node has finished syncing. The Ethereum World states is an structure that holds the latests state of every contract, it changes at every transaction and it takes a while to synchronize.

Comment: Tons of thanks for the explanation! Trying the fast mode now, seems to sync darn fast... and takes way less HDD. Waiting for it to finish to test :)

So basically once it's synced I'd be able to query it and send transactions through it, right ?

Comment: Yes, once it is synced you can query and send transactions. Since geth 1.10.4 the default on Ethereum is snap https://blog.ethereum.org/2021/03/03/geth-v1-10-0/#snap-sync.

Comment: My current status is `currentBlock: 9299906` `highestBlock: 9300016` and it never seems to catch up (on fast mode), what to do ?

Comment: There isn't much you can do but wait. It should eventually finish.

Comment: I think I got it, now it's syncing the states, currently it's on `knownStates: 237299711`. Do you know by chance what is the current amount on knownStates now, so I can understand how long more to wait (on Binance) ?

Comment: https://github.com/binance-chain/bsc/issues/104

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have a bsc node so I don't know the number of states.